# Upgrade VB6 Container Class to VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, vb6, vb6-migration

Okay, so I'm upgrading a VB6 app to VB.NET and I'm unsure of how to modernize the class_terminate component of a container class I'm building:

```
Private Sub class_terminate()
    If Not (colUserMappings Is Nothing) Then
        Set colUserMappings = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue is that the .NET equivalent of this `.Finalize` leaves open some potential runtime errors, because setting a container's final reference to nothing doesn't necessarily destroy the container, as .NET languages have non-deterministic finalization.

That being the case, how would I modernize the collections class in such a way that calling its terminate or finalize function would actually result in the destruction of the container at the end? Is there a good workaround for this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. The Garbage Collector will do the work for you.

Comment: Why do you need to destruct the container class before all references to it have been dropped?

Comment: So I can just discard the class_terminate() sub entirely for the new version?

Comment: Yes. You don't need it at all.

Comment: In fact, you wouldn't have needed to do this in VB6! That was just busy-code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not care too much about this. .Net is a managed, garbage-collected environment. I'm pretty sure the CLR will take care of collecting these objects for you when they're no longer needed.

As a general rule, you should only worry about these kind of things when you're getting a hold of unmanaged resources (such as files, DB Connections, COM objects, etc.). In that case, you may want to implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and properly release all your objects / resources in the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: It will be adding user access credentials from a DB Connection, but the container class itself isn't going to be managing the connections. So the CLR should handle it then?

Comment: @VK_Dev yes. for normal objects and classes, don't worry about setting them to `null`. .Net will handle that for you.